# Autmapper nested mapping

Tags: nested, mapping, automapper

I have the following main class:

```
public class ResearchOutcome 
{
    public ResearchOutcomeCategory ResearchOutcomeCategory { get; set; }
    public string? UniqueIdentifier { get; set; }
}
```

And the category class is:

```
public class ResearchOutcomeCategory 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
```

The View models for above classes are:

```
public class ResearchOutcomeDetailVm : IMapFrom<ResearchOutcome>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ResearchOutcomeCategoryDetailVm ResearchOutcomeCategory { get; set; }
}

public class ResearchOutcomeCategoryDetailVm : IMapFrom<ResearchOutcomeCategory>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I have used the following mapping profile:

```
   // First this one
        profile.CreateMap<ResearchOutcomeCategory, ResearchOutcomeCategoryDetailVm>();
        profile.CreateMap<ResearchOutcome, ResearchOutcomeDetailVm>();


   //Then I tried this one


        profile.CreateMap<ResearchOutcome, ResearchOutcomeDetailVm>()
            .ForMember(o => o.ResearchOutcomeCategory, 
                cat => cat.MapFrom( o => o.ResearchOutcomeCategory));
```

But the ResearchOutcomeCategory is always null. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging more, I identified that I was not "Including" the relevant item in the query, hence, the view model was always empty. Pretty dumb on my part :D

Regarding the mapping, if the properties (even complex ones) have the same names, then the mapper will map them automatically. So simply this line worked

```
            profile.CreateMap<ResearchOutcomeCategory, ResearchOutcomeCategoryDetailVm>();
```

Hope it helps someone

Comment: Note that if you use `ProjectTo`, the `Include` is no longer required.

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu, did not know that